# SQL Server deadlock when only inserting new rows without performing any selects

Tags: sql-server, sqlconnection, database-deadlocks, sqltransaction

I am seeing constant deadlocks in my app, even though it performs no select statements, no delete statements, and no update statements. It is only inserting completely new data.

**TL;DR**: It seems to be related to the foreign key. If I remove that then I don't get any deadlocks at all. But that is not an acceptable solution for obvious reasons.

Given the following table structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IncomingFile]
(
    [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL, 
    [ConcurrencyVersion] RowVersion NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_IncomingFile] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([Id])
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IncomingFileEvent]
(
    [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL, 
    [ConcurrencyVersion] RowVersion NOT NULL,
    [IncomingFileId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_IncomingFileEvent] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_IncomingFileEvent_IncomingFileId]
        FOREIGN KEY ([IncomingFileId])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[IncomingFile] ([Id])
)
GO
```

When I hit a number of concurrent tasks inserting data, I always see a deadlock. `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` is enabled in my DB options (even though I am not reading anyway).

Here is the code that will reproduce the problem. If you do not experience the problem, increase the `NumberOfTasksPerCpu` constant at the top of the program.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SqlServerDeadlockRepro
{
    class Program
    {
        private const int NumberOfTasksPerCpu = 8; // Keep increasing this by one if you do not get a deadlock!
        private const int NumberOfChildRows = 1_000;
        private const string MSSqlConnectionString = "Server=DESKTOP-G05BF1U;Database=EFCoreConcurrencyTest;Trusted_Connection=True;";

        private static int NumberOfConcurrentTasks;

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            NumberOfConcurrentTasks = Environment.ProcessorCount * NumberOfTasksPerCpu;

            var readySignals = new Queue<ManualResetEvent>();
            var trigger = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            var processingTasks = new List<Task>();
            for (int index = 0; index < NumberOfConcurrentTasks; index++)
            {
                var readySignal = new ManualResetEvent(false);
                readySignals.Enqueue(readySignal);
                var task = CreateDataWithSqlCommand(trigger, readySignal);
                processingTasks.Add(task);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for tasks to become ready");
            while (readySignals.Count > 0)
            {
                var readySignalBatch = new List<WaitHandle>();
                for(int readySignalCount = 0; readySignals.Count > 0 && readySignalCount < 64; readySignalCount++)
                {
                    readySignalBatch.Add(readySignals.Dequeue());
                }
                WaitHandle.WaitAll(readySignalBatch.ToArray());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Saving data");
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            trigger.Set();
            await Task.WhenAll(processingTasks.ToArray());
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Finished - " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }

        private static int TaskNumber = 0;
        private static async Task CreateDataWithSqlCommand(ManualResetEvent trigger, ManualResetEvent readySignal)
        {
            await Task.Yield();
            using var connection = new SqlConnection(MSSqlConnectionString);
            await connection.OpenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            var transaction = (SqlTransaction)await connection.BeginTransactionAsync(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted).ConfigureAwait(false);

            Console.WriteLine("Task " + Interlocked.Increment(ref TaskNumber) + $" of {NumberOfConcurrentTasks}  ready ");
            readySignal.Set();
            trigger.WaitOne();
            Guid parentId = Guid.NewGuid();
            string fileCommandSql = "insert into IncomingFile (Id) values (@Id)";
            using var fileCommand = new SqlCommand(fileCommandSql, connection, transaction);
            fileCommand.Parameters.Add("@Id", System.Data.SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = parentId;
            await fileCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            using var fileEventCommand = new SqlCommand
            {
                Connection = connection,
                Transaction = transaction
            };
            var commandTextBulder = new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO [IncomingFileEvent] ([Id], [IncomingFileId]) VALUES ");
            for (var i = 1; i <= NumberOfChildRows * 2; i += 2)
            {
                commandTextBulder.Append($"(@p{i}, @p{i + 1})");
                if (i < NumberOfChildRows * 2 - 1)
                    commandTextBulder.Append(',');

                fileEventCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@p{i}", Guid.NewGuid());
                fileEventCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@p{i + 1}", parentId);
            }

            fileEventCommand.CommandText = commandTextBulder.ToString();
            await fileEventCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            await transaction.CommitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Also tried making the primary key `NONCLUSTERED` and adding a `CLUSTERED` index based on the current date and time.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IncomingFile]
(
    [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL, 
    [ConcurrencyVersion] RowVersion NOT NULL,
    [CreatedUtc] DateTime2 DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_IncomingFile] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED([Id])
)
GO
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_IncomingFile_CreatedUtc] on [dbo].[IncomingFile]([CreatedUtc])
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IncomingFileEvent]
(
    [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL, 
    [ConcurrencyVersion] RowVersion NOT NULL,
    [IncomingFileId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [CreatedUtc] DateTime2 DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_IncomingFileEvent] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_IncomingFileEvent_IncomingFileId]
        FOREIGN KEY ([IncomingFileId])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[IncomingFile] ([Id])
)
GO
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_IncomingFileEvent_CreatedUtc] on [dbo].[IncomingFileEvent]([CreatedUtc])
GO
```

**UPDATE 2**

I tried a sequential guid taken from [here](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore/ValueGeneration/SequentialGuidValueGenerator.cs), which made no difference.

**UPDATE 3**

It seems to be related to the foreign key. If I remove that then I don't get any deadlocks at all.

**UPDATE 4**

A reply from Sql Server Product Group with some suggestions has been posted on my original github issue.

[https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/21899#issuecomment-683404734​​​​​​​](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/21899#issuecomment-683404734%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8B)

Comment: Options, make the primary keys as ` PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED` - this will make tables  heaps, you may still want to add artificial clustered index(identity, ...). Second option - if guids are not needed to be random, you could generate sequential guids from your code.

Comment: Just add an index or redo the primary key as suggested in the accepted answer.

Comment: Added the index, it made no difference. I also tried the composite PK and that also didn't fix it. Made the PK indexes NON CLUSTERED, still no difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The deadlock is due to the execution plan needed to check referential integrity. A full table scan of the `IncomingFile` table is performed when inserting a large number (1K) rows into the related `IncomingFileEvent` table. The scan acquires a shared table lock that's held for the duration of the transaction and leads to the deadlock when different sessions each hold an exclusive row lock on the just inserted `IncomingFile` row and are blocked by another sessions exclusive row lock.

Below is the execution plan that shows this:

[image: plan with full scan]

One way to avoid the deadlock is with an `OPTION (LOOP JOIN)` query hint on the `IncomingFileEvent` insert query:

```
    var commandTextBulder = new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO [IncomingFileEvent] ([Id], [IncomingFileId]) VALUES ");
    for (var i = 1; i <= NumberOfChildRows * 2; i += 2)
    {
        commandTextBulder.Append($"(@p{i}, @p{i + 1})");
        if (i < NumberOfChildRows * 2 - 1)
            commandTextBulder.Append(',');

        fileEventCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@p{i}", Guid.NewGuid());
        fileEventCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@p{i + 1}", parentId);
    }
    commandTextBulder.Append(" OPTION (LOOP JOIN);");
```

This is the plan with the hint:

[image: plan with hint]

On a side note, consider the changing the existing primary key to the one below. This is more correct from a data modeling perspective (identifying relationship) and will improve performance of both insert and selects since related rows are physically clustered together.

```
CONSTRAINT [PK_IncomingFileEvent] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(IncomingFileId, Id)
```

Comment: Thank you! Is this the only way (other than deleting the FK)? I ask because everywhere I look it is recommended not to pass join hints to the optimiser.

Comment: @PeterMorris, although not ideal, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query) states "we recommend only using hints as a last resort for experienced developers and database administrators". The hint is needed to avoid deadlocks when the `IncomingFile` table has only a few rows but will not be needed when the table is larger because SQL Server will then create the same plan as hinted version.

Comment: Why should sql server need to be told this at all? Other databases I tested didn't have this problem.

Comment: @PeterMorris, I seldom need to resort to hints in SQL Server but this is a worse-case scenario of dozens (on my workstation) of synchronized threads all hitting empty/small tables where the plan is optimized for performance rather than maximizing concurrency. There are other ways to improve performance without deadlocks. For example, I ran a single-threaded test of 1K iterations, each inserting an `IncomingFile` row and 1K related `IncomingFileEvent` rows via a table-valued parameter. The test ran in about 10 seconds, inserting 1M rows with the FK in place.

Comment: The problem is as soon as you have multiple threads updating at the same time. A fast single-user database isn't much use in 99.9% is cases :) I think I should report this as a bug.

Comment: It's arguable that this is a bug but feel free to report it on the [feedback forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server). Some application/schema designs are prone to deadlocks.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote the following extension to solve the problem for EF Core.

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
{
    base.OnConfiguring(options);
    options.UseLoopJoinQueries();
}
```

Using this code...

```
    public static class UseLoopJoinQueriesExtension
    {
        public static DbContextOptionsBuilder UseLoopJoinQueries(this DbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
        {
            if (builder is null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(builder));

            builder.AddInterceptors(new OptionLoopJoinCommandInterceptor());
            return builder;
        }
    }

    internal class OptionLoopJoinCommandInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor
    {
        public override Task<InterceptionResult<DbDataReader>> ReaderExecutingAsync(DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            AppendOptionToSql(command);
            return Task.FromResult(result);
        }

        public override InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result)
        {
            AppendOptionToSql(command);
            return result;
        }

        private static void AppendOptionToSql(DbCommand command)
        {
            const string OPTION_TEXT = " OPTION (LOOP JOIN)";
            string[] commands = command.CommandText.Split(";");

            for (int index = 0; index < commands.Length; index++)
            {
                string sql = commands[index].Trim();
                if (sql.StartsWith("insert into ", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                    || sql.StartsWith("select ", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                    || sql.StartsWith("delete ", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                    || sql.StartsWith("merge ", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    commands[index] += OPTION_TEXT;
                }
            }

#pragma warning disable CA2100 // Review SQL queries for security vulnerabilities
            command.CommandText = string.Join(";\r\n", commands);
#pragma warning restore CA2100 // Review SQL queries for security vulnerabilities
        }
    }
```